# Horizontal aligning dash checklist label

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

How can I set the label of a checkbox to the left side of the checkbox instead of to the right side with plotly dash?
In Excel (VBA) the 'Horizontal-align' variable allows you to place the label differently with respect to the checkbox, but I can't seem to find a similar option for Dash.

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpEtn.png)

[But this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaEOn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap your `input` and `labels` into a `div` where you make the parent class `position: relative` and then having the input and label as `position: absolute`

Example HTML:

```
<div>
    <form class="formclass">
        <div class="inputContainer">
            <input class="inputClass" type="checkbox"></input>
            <label class="labelClass">Label1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="inputContainer">
            <input class="inputClass" type="checkbox"></input>
            <label class="labelClass">Label2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="inputContainer">
            <input class="inputClass" type="checkbox"></input>
            <label class="labelClass">Label3</label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.inputContainer{
     position:relative;
     height: 50px;
     width: 80px;
}
.labelClass{
     position: absolute;
 }
.inputClass{
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
 }
```